# neo4j "csv load" extra character

Tags: csv, neo4j, cypher

1) I have a simple csv file having 7 languages in it. File content looks like this:

[image: File content's screen shot]

2) I import all 7 languages successfully with this command:

```
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:C:/Language.csv' AS line
MERGE (l:Language { Name: line[0] })
RETURN l.Name AS Language
```

[image]

3) After importing, this query for 'Turkish' returns no result

```
match (l: Language {Name:'Turkish'}) return l
```

[image: query with no result]

4) However, queries for other languages return proper results. ie: Greek

```
match (l: Language {Name:'Greek'}) return l
```

[image: greek results]

5) I suspect an extra invisible character. this query works:

```
match (l: Language)
where l.Name =~ '.*Turkish*.'
return l
```

[image: like turkish results]

Question: How and why can this be?

Additional Google Chrome Response Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Mustafa, can you provide a link where we can get the CSV file?

Comment: Hello Jim, thank you for your answer. i have just identified the problem. My file is formatted with BOM. When i saved it as "UTF-8 Without BOM" the problem resolved. I wonder if there's an option to make neo4j work for files with BOM, too.

Comment: Mustafa, there's not an option to make Neo4j recognize an initial BOM field, but can you add a header line to your file? You could use "LOAD CSV WITH HEADER", but otherwise leave your Cypher statement as-is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've identified the problem as my csv file being "UTF-8 with BOM". When i saved it as "UTF-8 without BOM" the problem resolved.